# GCP Secret Manager Access "Invalid Grant" error 503 with Python 3.11

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python, google, gcp

really losing it here. I wrote a simple piece of code just to be able to access secrets, and every time I run it it simply throws the following error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Deadline of 60.0s exceeded while calling target function, last exception: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('invalid_grant: Bad Request', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'})
```

Below is my code:

```
from google.cloud import secretmanager

def secretFinder(projectid, secretid, version):

    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    name = f"projects/{projectid}/secrets/{secretid}/versions/{version}"
    response = client.access_secret_version(name=name)
    return response.payload.data.decode('UTF-8')

secretFinder("my_project", "test", "latest")
```

My CLI is auth'd with my service account, which contains the following roles associated with it -

```
Owner
Secret Manager Admin
Secret Manager Secret Accessor
```

I confirmed only my account is auth'd by running

```
gcloud auth list
```

Next, I ensured I set the correct project by running

```
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

Where project id is "my_project". I did not use the project #, but instead the actual project ID as directed.

Ironically, if I run the following via cli I actually get my secret:

```
gcloud secrets versions access --secret=test latest
```

I truly don't know what to do at this point and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Run `gcloud auth application-default login` and try again.

If that does not work, move this question to Stack Overflow. Add details on the environment you are running the code on.

Note: the CLI `gcloud` uses different credentials than your code. Your code is using ADC (Application Default Credentials), which is why you must authenticate using `application-default` command option.

Your other option is to modify your code and specify the service account as a parameter to `SecretManagerServiceClient()`.